# Display in the same page with ajax the products from a specific category - ajax, laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have some problem with a task. I'm not very good with javascript. Please help.

I display the categories as a button and I want when the button is pressed to display the products assigned to each category, also the products to be in the form of a button. In the next task I have to make sure that when the product button is pressed, that product is added to a list, also without refreshing the page.

**Controler:**

```
public function categories($id)
{
    $table = Table::find($id);
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('products', compact('table', 'categories'));
}
public function products($id)
{
    $products = Products::find($id);
    $response = '<button class="btn btn-dark product-button">{{$product->name}}</button>';
    return response()->json([
        'response' => $response
    ]);
}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/masa/{id}','HomeController@categories')->name('table');
Route::get('/produse', 'HomeController@produse')->name('products');
```

**Blade**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row title">
            <h2 style="text-align: center;  margin: auto;">{{$table->name}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 product-table">
                <div class="row">
                    <button class="btn btn-dark product-button">
                        {{$table->name}}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 product-table">
                <div class="row">
                    {{--Categorii--}}
                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <button class="btn btn-dark product-button" id="cat-{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</button>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <hr><br>
                <div class="row" id="products">
                    <button class="btn btn-dark product-button">Product Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twbs-pagination/1.3.1/jquery.twbsPagination.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.5/validator.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    {{--<script src="{{asset('/js/script.js')}}"></script>--}}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('select[cat-{{$category->id}}]').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax(
                url: "{{route('products')}}",
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'category': '{{$category->name}}',
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.product-table').after(data.response);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: So, when category is selected, you want to display all product of that category using ajax call so that page refreshment is not necessary

Comment: Yes and I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with the above code, but I've done similar thing with two selectors. one for category another for products. When category is selected then ajax call is made and then all the product associated with that category are retrieved and displayed in another selector.

Comment: It's quite large to post here if you want please tell me.

Comment: Can you send me the exemple by email? Please. :)

Comment: I'll try to add here wait some minute

Comment: I've added my solution have a try and if helpful to you let me know :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DB structure should be,

**Migrations**

**Category**

```
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
```

**Product**

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('products');
}
```

**Category Model**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    //
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

**Product Model**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    //
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Now, you should have Controller file like this:

**DropDownController**

```
class DropDownController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function index(){

        $categories = Category::all();
        $products = Product::all();

        return view('dropdown.dropdown', compact('categories','products'));
    }

    public function getProducts($id){
        if($id!=0){
            $products = Category::find($id)->products()->select('id', 'name')->get()->toArray();
        }else{
            $products = Product::all()->toArray();
        }
        return response()->json($products);
    }
}
```

Your routes should be like,

**Route**

```
Route::get('/dropdown','DropDownController@index');
Route::get('category/{id}/products', 'DropDownController@getProducts');
```

After this, In your edit form where you want to show associated product of a category make something like this.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Category</label>
            <select class="form-control" name = "category">
                <option value="0">Please Select Category</option>
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Products</label>
            <select class="form-control" name = "product">
                <option value="0">Please Select Product</option>
                @foreach($products as $product)
                    <option value="{{$product->id}}">{{$product->name}}</option>
                @endforeach

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Your ajax script like,

**AJAX**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('select[name=category]').on('change', function () {
        var selected = $(this).find(":selected").attr('value');
        $.ajax({
                    url: base_url + '/category/'+selected+'/products/',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',

            }).done(function (data) {

                var select = $('select[name=product]');
                select.empty();
                select.append('<option value="0" >Please Select Product</option>');
                $.each(data,function(key, value) {
                    select.append('<option value=' + key.id + '>' + value.name + '</option>');
                });
                console.log("success");
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

This is quite large but easy to understand how it works. I hope you will understand.

Comment: If you need any thing in above code to be explained feel free to ask :)